# read textscan file with NA as empty matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a text file D with n-rows and 5 columns that I want to read. Every row will represent a vector. However where value is equal to NA I want to leave it empty:

D:

```
122 12 10 NA NA
110 10 30 45 87 
110 12 10 NA NA
..
```

I'm doing this:

```
bid = fopen(D,'r');
bfile = textscan(bid,'%d %d %d %s %s','TreatAsEmpty',{'NA'})
var=122;
IndVar=bfile {:,1}==var;
rest=bfile(:,[2:end])
vecVar=rest(IndVar)
```

I wnat to get vectors from row without NA:
vecVar =[12 10];  [10 30 45 87 ]; [ 12 10];

I try this:

```
rest= rest(~isnan(rest));
```

I get error:

Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

I've been playing for over an hour now still cannot figure it out..
Any help will be very much appreciated!

many thanks!

Comment: If you type `size(rest)` in the Command window, what do you get?

Comment: @CST-Link size (rest) gives ans= 1  4. Although should be n-row X 4..

Comment: The thing is, `textscan` is useful to get the data *by columns*, but you need the data filtered by row.

Comment: @CST-Link any particular command you could suggest?

Comment: unfortunately there's easy to replace textscan. Working on a solution. Meanwhile, question: only the last two columns can contain `NA`? or all of them?

Comment: it is important to not make assumptions... is it possible that all the columns may have NA values? not necessarily in all rows?

Comment: No never ALL columns are NA..2 last columns most often. in some cases 4 columns. I have 10 columns in real data.

Comment: I updated my code in the posting to not make any assumption about the columns, so you can safely use it. Is still for 5 columns (because this is in the original question).

Comment: Updated my posting to easily change the number of columns (one variable).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error message, [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) only works on numeric arrays. To operate on a cell array of numeric arrays, use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) which will apply a command to each cell in an array. As an aside, [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) internally is actually a number (either a single or a double), so you will want to use the numeric version of `NaN` instead of the text string `'NA'` for your empty values, and [`var`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html) is a built-in command, so you will want to change that variable name.

You will need to clarify a little, but as far as I understand, given the input file containing the matrix:

```
122 12 10 NA NA
110 10 30 45 87 
110 12 10 NA NA
```

you expect:

```
vecVar ={...
    [12 10];
    [10 30 45 87 ];
    [12 10]
    };
```

In my first answer, I missed the fact that you were reading in with integers. This will give the result above, which I think is what you are after:

```
bid = fopen(d,'r');
% integers don't have NaN, so read in as float instead.
% also, collect everything into a single matrix because it makes it.
% easier to debug
bfile = textscan(bid,'%f %f %f %f, %f', 'TreatAsEmpty', 'NA', 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(D);

% convert from a cell to a matrix to make i
bfile = bfile{1};
var=122;
IndVar = bfile(:,1) == var;
rest = bfile(:, 2:end);

% Turn the matrix back into a cell with each row a single cell
[nrows, ncols] = size(rest);
rest = mat2cell(rest, ones(nrows, 1), ncols);

% get rid of the NaN values
rest = cellfun(@(x) x(~isnan(x)), rest, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This will produce a cell array where each element contains a vector that can be retrieved using `desired_vector = rest{index_of_your_choice};`

Comment: Thank you. However, I get this error: Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in @(x)all(~isnan(x))... When I use %d isntead of string rest(IndVar) gives me ans = 

    [90x1 int32] when I should get 1 x 4..What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes thank you! I got 'rest' which is cell array. How do I convert it to normal vector?

Comment: also this answer sets 'rest' to 90 x 2 array..When it is different in the second row..it has 4 columns yet still reads only first 2 columns..

Comment: A couple issues I missed before and will update my answer with. First, you are reading in the last two columns as strings, so `isnan` doesn't know what to do with those. If you read them in as integers (`%d`), there is no integer `NaN`. `NaN` can _only_ be a single or a double.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that puts in the cell array `val` each row of numeric values:

```
    %'Number of columns'
    NC = 5;

    %'Read the strings'
    f = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
    raw= textscan(f, repmat('%s',1,NC));
    fclose(f);
    if numel(raw) ~= NC
            error('Something is wrong with the file format');
    else
            NR = numel(raw{1});
    end;

    %'Convert data'
    for c = 1:NC
            for r = 1:NR
                    raw{c}{r} = sscanf(raw{c}{r}, '%d');
            end;
    end;

    %'Concatenate rows into val'
    val = cell(1,NR);
    buf = cell(1,NC);
    for r = 1:NR
            for c = 1:NC
                    buf{c} = raw{c}{r};
            end;
            val{r} = [buf{:}];
    end;
```

You can't use a normal matrix to store the values, because there are rows with different numbers of values. That means that the row vectors can be stored only into cell arrays.

Comment: Thank you. took me a while to get this code. I get my 'val' from the previous code. I wonder how do I access row where first column is equal to 'val'?

Comment: @mil not sure that I understand the question. But, with the code that I provided, one gets the first row by `val{1}`, second row by `val{2}` etc. To get the first column in the second row, one can write `val{2}(1)`. To find out how many columns are in the third row, one can use `numel(val{3})`. Please note that if you try to access columns that originally had the value `NA`, you'll get an error.

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid. But I still cannot figure it out. I wrote in my code val=122;IndVar=bfile {:,1}==val;. I get 'val' value from somewhere before. So I wonder how do I get the row (with columns from 2:NC) where first column==122..i.e.I used index IndVar..